# What happens to un-routed messages when filters are used?

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have a large number of un-routed messages for an address where all the queues have a filter. I only need a small subset of the messages the publisher sends -- so that's how I've been filtering them.

Is this a terrible idea? What happens to un-routed messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using queues with filters is the recommended way to keep consumers from getting messages they don't care about. This is *much* more efficient (although sometimes less flexible) than configuring the filter on the consumer itself.

Messages which are sent to an address and then are not routed to any queue (e.g. because the filters don't match) are simply discarded by default.